# SweetAlert input validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the alert to not disappear when the user is trying to submit an empty form,instead it should show some error in the same alert.I tried doing swal.showInputError("some error") but it  gives an error that it is not 
 valid function.I tried looking at the documentation but cannot find any...

Here is my code-

```
    swal({
     title:"Enter a Username",
     content: {
                element: "input",
                attributes: {
                    placeholder: "Type your username",
                    type: "text"
                     },
             },


    className: "mySwal"
    }).then((username)=>{
            //get the username
            if(username){

            }else{


            }

});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
inputValidator: (value) => {
    return !value && 'You need to write something!'
  }
```

This will validates if the user is writing a value.

Comment: this is not working, please advise which version you are using

Comment: sweet alert 2 - 7.15.1

Answer (score 1):

This works to me

```
inputValidator: (value) => {
        if (!value) return 'Your text here'
        else return null
      }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to the community. Please provide explanation on your answer. This looks very similar to the accepted answer. Why did you post it? The accepted answer was not working? Which version of SweetAlert are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This will also Work

```
showCancelButton: true,
            preConfirm: (value) => {

                if (!value) {
                    Swal.showValidationMessage(
                        'You need to write something!'
                    )
                }
            }
```